# Polymer build error while using polymerfire

Tags: firebase, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer

When trying to build using polymer fire, I'm getting this error, has anyone seen this before?

What does 'no resolver found' mean?

`error:   Promise rejection: Error: no resolver found for ../../../../bower_components/firebase/firebase.js`

The import I have is

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
```

The version of polymerfire I'm using is

```
"polymerfire": "firebase/polymerfire#^0.9.3",
```

Full error log:

```
error:   Promise rejection: Error: no resolver found for ../../../../bower_components/firebase/firebase.js
error:   Error: no resolver found for ../../../../bower_components/firebase/firebase.js
    at FileLoader.request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/hydrolysis/lib/loader/file-loader.js:70:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/vulcanize/lib/vulcan.js:318:26)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Object.inlineScripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/vulcanize/lib/vulcan.js:311:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/vulcanize/lib/vulcan.js:458:21)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:89:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:102:28
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/core-js/modules/_microtask.js:18:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
error:   Promise rejection: Error: no resolver found for ../../../../bower_components/firebase/firebase.js
error:   Error: no resolver found for ../../../../bower_components/firebase/firebase.js
    at FileLoader.request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/hydrolysis/lib/loader/file-loader.js:70:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/vulcanize/lib/vulcan.js:318:26)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Object.inlineScripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/vulcanize/lib/vulcan.js:311:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/vulcanize/lib/vulcan.js:458:21)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:89:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:102:28
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/core-js/modules/_microtask.js:18:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Theres is defiantly a a firebase.js located at bower_components/firebase/firebase.js